# How to customise numbering in order to subdivide a single section into two parts?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, article

I have an article class document. I am trying to divide a "section" into two parts such that a letter is added to the section number for the different parts. By "dividing" I mean visually, programming-wise I guess it is just customising the numbering. My aim is to have sections numbered in the following way:

1 Some Section

1.1 Some Subsection

2A Some Section

2A.1 Some Subsection

2A.1.1 Some Subsubsection

2B Some Section

2B.1 Some Subsection

2B.2 Some Subsection

3 Some Section

3.1 Some Subsection

I think the idea would be to create a new `\section`-like command, or set of commands, that allows the creation of a new section with a custom letter attached to it (or with something that tracks if the previous section has a letter). However, this command should not affect the usual `\section` command as I still want to be able to use the usual numbering before and after the subdivided section (or sections).

I have tried to implement the case where I divide a single section into two (A and B) using the approach of the accepted answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63112/numbering-sections-as-1a-1b-2a-2b-etc). However, this answer is thought for a document where all sections are divided into A and B, while I just want to divide one section. Therefore, after using the new command they create (`\sectionB`), if I use `\section` again a letter is still added to the numbering.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enclose the changes in the section counters in an environment to be used like `amsmath`'s `subequations` environment. I think the following example should do what you wanted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{outersection}
\newenvironment{dividedsection}{%
    \let\oldthesection\thesection
    \setcounter{outersection}{\value{section}}
    \stepcounter{outersection}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{outersection}\Alph{section}}
}{%
    \setcounter{section}{\value{outersection}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\oldthesection}
}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{dividedsection}
\section{Half of a divided section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\section{The other half}
\end{dividedsection}
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!